# How to caculuate this elementary calculus problem?

Tags: calculus

Question:

A piece of cardboard is 1 meter by 1/2 meter. A square is to be cut from each corner and the sides folded up to make an open-top box. What are the dimensions of the box with maximum possible volume?

My solution:

Denote the length of square is $x$, hence

$V=(1-2x)(\frac{1}{2}-2x)x=4x^3-3x^2+\frac{1}{2}x\Rightarrow V'=12x^2-6x+\frac{1}{2}=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt3}{12}$,

Then test by second derivative:

$V''=24x-6$, in order to maximize the volumn thus $V''<0\Rightarrow x=\frac{3-\sqrt3}{12}$.

So my result is $V=\frac{\sqrt3}{72},S=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{6}$.

But the correct answer is: $\frac{5-2\sqrt3}{24}$.

Where is wrong in my solution??? Thanks!

Comment: So, why do you know the "correct answer"?

Comment: It's an exercise from Ohio MOOC calculus textbook, and they provide the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are correct if you wrote the question correctly.

Comment: Sorry I am not an English speaker. What does "dimension" mean in this problem? Area or volume? Thank you!

Comment: I thought it represents 'area'. If $S$ represents the surface area of the box, $S$ is correct, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write $\frac12 - 2x$ not $\frac 12 -x$ in the formula for the volume.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's a typing error. But my calculation is 2x.